# Problem with CORS in nextjs13 and azure blob storage

Tags: cors, azure-blob-storage, next.js13

I need to upload images to **Azure Blob Storage using Next.js 13** and a server component to avoid having to use the /api folder. The image is uploading without any issues, but it's showing the following error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6rLz.png)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZTQU.png)

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } from '@azure/storage-blob'
import nanoId from '@/utils/nanoId'

export default function UploaderOneImage() {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()

    const onClickSave = async (formData: any) => {
        if (formData.files[0]) {
            const newFileName = nanoId() + '.' + formData.files[0].name.split('.').pop()

            const account = 'serlismaldonado'
            const sas = 'SASEXAMPLE'
            const containerName = 'diagnostics'

            const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}`,
            )

            const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)

            const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(newFileName)

            const options = {
                blobHTTPHeaders: {
                    blobContentType: formData.files[0].type,
                },
            }

            const blob = await blobClient.uploadBrowserData(formData.files[0], options)

            if (blob) {
                console.log('File uploaded')
            } else {
                console.log('File not uploaded')
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Upload</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onClickSave)}>
                <input type='file' {...register('files', { required: true })} />
                <button type='submit'>Save!</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

I'm facing difficulties in resolving the error I mentioned earlier. Could someone please assist me in fixing it?

Comment: You need to set CORS headers on your Storage account using the Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: `formData.files[0].name.split('.').pop()` <-- Don't do this.

Comment: `const blob = await blobClient.uploadBrowserData(...)` <-- You need to wrap this in a `try/catch/finally` and gracefully handle any caught `err`.

Comment: Man! it's works!

Comment: @SerlisMaldonado Maldonado please post your answer So it helps others

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer for the benefit of the community:-

Thank you for the comments, @Dai, about `formData.files[0]. name.split('.'). pop()` and try/catch/finally

- I followed this [reference](https://github.com/kurab/next-azure-storage) code.

```js
export default function UploaderOneImage() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onClickSave = async (formData) => {
    if (formData.files[0]) {
      const newFileName = nanoId() + '.' + formData.files[0].name.split('.').pop();

      const account = '<storage_name>';
      const sas = '<SAS>';
      const containerName = '<container_name>';

      const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}`,
        new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, sas)
      );

      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

      const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(newFileName);

      const options = {
        blobHTTPHeaders: {
          blobContentType: formData.files[0].type,
        },
      };

      try {
        const blob = await blobClient.uploadBrowserData(formData.files[0], options);

        if (blob) {
          console.log('File uploaded');
        } else {
          console.log('File not uploaded');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Upload</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onClickSave)}>
        <input type='file' {...register('files', { required: true })} />
        <button type='submit'>Save!</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Output:**

The file was uploaded successfully as below:

[image]

***Azure Portal :***

[image]